# Query with BETWEEN returns Zero or ONE

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT `fecha` BETWEEN '1390950000' AND '1391126400',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', `idItem`, `nombreItem`, `cantidad`, `diferencia`) ORDER BY `idItem`) schedule
FROM inventarioStat
GROUP BY fecha ASC;
```

The problem is in the BETWEEN part. It returns zero or one? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you expect that to return?  `BETWEEN` returns TRUE (1) or FALSE (0).  It's working just as you had written it.

Comment: Based on what you seem to be expecting, you probably meant for your  `BETWEEN` to be in a `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Gordon answer was right , only now returns those two dates, not the range between those dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL treats comparison operations as booleans, which take on a value of 0 or 1.

You have put a `between` in the `select` clause.  So, it is returning either `0` (for false) or `1` (for true).  The same would be true of other comparison operators, such as `=`, `<>`, `<=` and so on.

Presumably, you want it in a `where` clause:

```
SELECT fecha,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', `idItem`, `nombreItem`, `cantidad`, `diferencia`) ORDER BY `idItem`
                   ) as schedule
FROM inventarioStat
WHERE `fecha` BETWEEN '1390950000' AND '1391126400'
GROUP BY fecha ASC;
```